# Concatenating two Float columns and insert them to another Float column in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, concatenation, nvarchar

I am dealing with a situation as mentioned in question:

I got two `Float` columns which I want to concatenate like so:

```
(Column1 + '_' + Column2)
```

and insert them into `column3`.

I think the correct query would be something like this:

```
Update Table as A
set A.Column3 = select ((Column1 + '_' + Column2),ID ) as B
where A.ID = B.ID
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: And your question is? You have a functional code, did you tested? Which are the results? Did you had some error?

Comment: I have two float columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make sure to avoid getting NULLs, you'd need to use something like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET Column3 = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), ISNULL(Column1, N'')) + N'_' + 
              CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), ISNULL(Column2, N''))
```

assuming all three columns are in the same table. Otherwise you'd need to use a `JOIN` in your `UPDATE`

**Update:** since those are `FLOAT` column, they need to be converted to `NVARCHAR` using the `CONVERT` function

Comment: Dear mark i get the following error: Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

Comment: Sorry, I made a big mistake. the two columns are in Float type.

Answer (score 2):

Try this untested Query:

```
update a
set A.Column3  = (Column1 +'_'+Column2 )
from Table a
    inner join select * from B on A.ID=B.ID
```